# Using sql initial data in Django with heroku?

Tags: sql, django, heroku

Why when i use sql files and load my initial data via sql statements and when deploying the app on heroku,the sql files aren't executed and no data found in the database by default,and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku does not use the SQLlite database. You have to use Heroku's shared postgresql database since heroku is a 'production' environment.

When you push a django app up to heroku, it overrides your database settings in your settings.py file. You have to do a syncdb or south migration to your production postresql database your app now uses.

Btw - you will need to install postgres on your devel environment and  pip install psycopg2 for postgres/python support.